# Split date string with dashes

Tags: jquery, date, split

I have a date value in this format: 20160810

I need to split it into a proper date format like so: 2016-08-10

In jquery, how would I achieve this? I can't use split() because it has to have a delimiter to reference, so I'm not sure if there's a function that can split based on the number of characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var res = '20160810'.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3')

console.log(res);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/jW2qE8/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or with **[`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method

```js
var str = '20160810';

var res = str.slice(0, 4) + '-' + str.slice(4,6) + '-' + str.slice(-2);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hm, you were faster with that! :)

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful to have both options.

Comment: @Eckstein : glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Good Morning!

Maybe you try to use the **substr()** function. This functions cuts an substring out of your string, based on an beginning and ending charindex:

```
var string = "20160810";
var date = string.substr(0,3)+"-"+string.substr(4,5)+"-"+string.substr(6,7);
```

This is also possible with an regex:

```
var string = "20160810";
var date = string.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2-$3'); //2016-08-10
```

In the second example you use the capturing groups to capture three decimals of different lengths and replace them with themselves separated with an `-`.

I hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not into doing things with RegExp:

```js
var dateArray = '20160810'.split('')
var year = dateArray.slice(0,4).join('')
var month = dateArray.slice(4,6).join('')
var day = dateArray.slice(6).join('')
console.log([year, month, day].join('-'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js):

```
> moment("20160810", "YYYYMMDD").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
'2016-08-10'
```

Comment: it's a great library, only one I trust with my dates and times these days